# How to generate n different colors for any natural number n?

Tags: algorithm, colors, pseudocode, perception

Say n = 100; How do I generate 100 visually distinct colors? Is this mathematically possible?

Comment: Agree with David. This is a subjective problem. What if I was colour blind?

Comment: Color difference is not subjective: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference

Comment: This question has been asked to death.  Here is a good algorithm for visually distinct: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103368/color-logic-algorithm  It it not too difficult to come up with n numbers approx. equally distributed in this color space

Comment: @BlueRaja: the distance function is only part of the problem. How do you pick the colors from the color space so that the distance between them is maximal?

Comment: @Otto: Colour difference might not be, but 'visually distinct' is.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470690/how-to-automatically-generate-n-distinct-colors/4382138#4382138

Comment: @Aryabhatta if you're color blind it depends on which type and in that case there are lines of confusion you'd have and we can draw those within XYZ colorspace and still make different maximally different color elements for you. In fact, more and more games and applications are properly dealing with color blindness and using distinct colors schemes taking that into account.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

100 is a lot of colours, but you might be able to do it by distributing them as sparsely as possible in the HSB or HSL space; doing it in RGB is probably difficult.

For example, you might decide to use 10 different hues, 4 different saturation levels, and 3 different brightness settings, that would give you up to 120 colours.  You'll need to pick the saturation and brightness values carefully; human eyes are complicated and confusing sensors.  If you treat the colour space as a cone, you will probably want a different number of hues at each lightness/saturation level.

Here's a link to the wikipedia [entry on HSB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV).

Comment: The problem with doing this in HSL space is that all colors with 0 lightness are the same; and colors with the same lightness and 0 saturation are the same. So points that seem to be far apart turn out not to be visually distinct. It actually seems better to me to distribute the colors sparsely in RGB.

Comment: @Jason: Who said you need to treat the color space as a cube? (Although RGB is easier.)

Comment: Yeah, 'as sparsely as possible' is probably not what I meant to say.  The second paragraph clears things up a bit, but I'll edit that end clean it up.

Comment: I take it back, I do mean 'as sparsely as possible'.  Just treat the HSB colour space as a cone.

Comment: The real problem with HSB (or HSL)--whether as a cube, cone or sphere--is that [hue values distributed by equal numeric separation do not produce equal amounts of visual separation](http://phrogz.net/tmp/colordifferences/). HSB is way better than using RGB, but you need non-linear mappings along the axes to get the best visual separation.

Answer (score 48):

Yeah. Defining distinct is a product of deferring to a color space then when we say maximally distinct colors what we mean to say is colors which are as far from all the other colors as possible. But since the color space doesn't change the answer isn't going to change. And implementing something that better fits with human eyes and how human eyes see color like CIE-lab de2000 color distance makes redoing all the calculations hard, but makes a static list easy. Here's 128 entries.

```
private static final String[] indexcolors = new String[]{
        "#000000", "#FFFF00", "#1CE6FF", "#FF34FF", "#FF4A46", "#008941", "#006FA6", "#A30059",
        "#FFDBE5", "#7A4900", "#0000A6", "#63FFAC", "#B79762", "#004D43", "#8FB0FF", "#997D87",
        "#5A0007", "#809693", "#FEFFE6", "#1B4400", "#4FC601", "#3B5DFF", "#4A3B53", "#FF2F80",
        "#61615A", "#BA0900", "#6B7900", "#00C2A0", "#FFAA92", "#FF90C9", "#B903AA", "#D16100",
        "#DDEFFF", "#000035", "#7B4F4B", "#A1C299", "#300018", "#0AA6D8", "#013349", "#00846F",
        "#372101", "#FFB500", "#C2FFED", "#A079BF", "#CC0744", "#C0B9B2", "#C2FF99", "#001E09",
        "#00489C", "#6F0062", "#0CBD66", "#EEC3FF", "#456D75", "#B77B68", "#7A87A1", "#788D66",
        "#885578", "#FAD09F", "#FF8A9A", "#D157A0", "#BEC459", "#456648", "#0086ED", "#886F4C",
        
        "#34362D", "#B4A8BD", "#00A6AA", "#452C2C", "#636375", "#A3C8C9", "#FF913F", "#938A81",
        "#575329", "#00FECF", "#B05B6F", "#8CD0FF", "#3B9700", "#04F757", "#C8A1A1", "#1E6E00",
        "#7900D7", "#A77500", "#6367A9", "#A05837", "#6B002C", "#772600", "#D790FF", "#9B9700",
        "#549E79", "#FFF69F", "#201625", "#72418F", "#BC23FF", "#99ADC0", "#3A2465", "#922329",
        "#5B4534", "#FDE8DC", "#404E55", "#0089A3", "#CB7E98", "#A4E804", "#324E72", "#6A3A4C",
        "#83AB58", "#001C1E", "#D1F7CE", "#004B28", "#C8D0F6", "#A3A489", "#806C66", "#222800",
        "#BF5650", "#E83000", "#66796D", "#DA007C", "#FF1A59", "#8ADBB4", "#1E0200", "#5B4E51",
        "#C895C5", "#320033", "#FF6832", "#66E1D3", "#CFCDAC", "#D0AC94", "#7ED379", "#012C58"
};
```

Here's the first 256 as an image.

[image: max distance]

(left-to-right) (top-to-bottom). You might be able to get a few more distinct colors if you made sure each color was as equidistant as possible within the colorspace. That lookup table picks each additional color as maximally distinct from all previous colors rather than designating the N at the start and then mapping out the colorspace. So yeah, brute force and a high level color distance algorithm and you're set to make this same set of colors yourself. Over the course of a day or so.

---

If you do set lists and make them equidistant you can get a distinct number between different colors for example,
[image: 5 colors],
Beats the default list at 5 colors which was at min_delta_max 53.2 with min_delta_max 61.5

Or the colors in the list, [image: 10 color list],
#156FC3 #165859 #24C4FF #30A581 #957D5C #213E02 #DE9AF5 #68D840 #6E0062 #C25B77 which exceeds the first ten elements in the precomputed list.

If you wanted to try this instead:
https://gist.github.com/tatarize/a483db49993e6e0e994ad82ba3e2a22e

Can be edited to take `num_of_colors`, and you can run it for a long time and get a set of colors which should have a lower overall min_delta_max (the biggest maximum minimum distances between any two colors in the list). You'd still want a precompiled list.

Comment: Sometimes simple is beautiful. Thanks.

Comment: Something is wrong with your image. [`FFFF00`](http://www.colorhexa.com/ffff00) is certainly not lime.

Comment: I ran the code on two different instances and changed an equals so it seems to have gone with "#FFFF00" as the second color. With a second color as yellow rather than green, it bounced around to different values. They are both technically correct. As they are maximally distant but there are apparently different valid answers for what color is the most unlike black. Depending on whether my value is >= current furthest or just > current furthest. I'll update the graphic.

Comment: Not super sure, but triple checked the code. It produced the given static list. Exported a newer color image using the correct values with a lot more values (since I ran it up into the high 200s).

Comment: @Tatarize I'm using the first 5 after black and they're superb, thanks! Though now you have me really curious how they would differ if just these 5 (or 6) were generated equidistant as you mentioned. I looked for code on your blog but didn't find any so I may never know. 

Comment: @ChristopherGalpin I cannot guarantee a result before the heat death of the universe but here's some python code to give you an answer.

https://gist.github.com/tatarize/ade134305086663b0503f0c413af77e8

Keep in mind when, I ran the above brute force thing it took me a month, though each got progressively harder with more results. And the attempt here is to for phase 2, manipulate each color to gradually improve the whole, which means 6 * 3 different color components need either a +1, 0, -1 across the entire set of results. And to keep trying until improvement stops.

Comment: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/3302478/153757526-2410f73d-ffb1-4b9d-97dd-83dcc3fa60c3.png provides a somewhat naive early result there. The distances between each additional goes 101.2, 79.6, 58.3, 53.2. This quickly goes up to 54 before it hits a bunch of code that seems to take ages since its trying to many bit manipulations.

Comment: Combined the pair checking code with some brute force adjustment code to unjam things it still needs to brute force prove 18 different color components can't get changed across 3 different operations.
56.429232872431825: #002600 #C5FF00 #06E6FD #C505FF #FF4846

Comment: Ran it for a day. At 5, your values are: #00004A #FEFF2C #FF8AFF #00FFF5 #AE1400. This is about 61.62 rather than 53.2 or so.

Answer (score 37):

Edit:

I don't have any expertise in this area and my math skills are pretty average. But I have the opinion that the solution to this problem is more complex and interesting than many answers here suggest, since I tried to do something similar recently and didn't find a solution.

### Color Difference

The perception of color is of course subjective, but there is significant agreement between humans. For example, we can all agree that red, green and blue are very different colors, and even colorblind people agree that black and white are very different.

#### RGB

The most common representation of color in computer systems is the vector *(r, g, b)* which suggests a simple distance function like

[image: RGB color difference]

Lets set the range for *r*, *g* and *b* to *[0, 1]* and see how this works:

1. Red *(1, 0, 0)* and red *(1, 0, 0)* has the distance of **0**, which should be obvious
2. Red *(1, 0, 0)* and yellow *(1, 1, 0)* has the distance of **1**, which is smaller than the distance of
3. Red *(1, 0, 0)* and blue *(0, 0, 1)* which is **sqrt(2)**, which is plausible

So far, so good. The problem however is that blue and red have the same distance **1** from black *(0, 0, 0)*, but when looking at the image this doesn't seem to hold true:

[image: blue and red on black]

Also yellow *(1, 1, 0)* and  magenta *(1, 0, 1)* both have have the same distance **1** from white *(1, 1, 1)*, which doesn't seem to make sense either:

[image: yellow and magenta on white]

#### HSL and HSV

I think it is safe to assume that analogue metrics for the [HSL and HSV color schemes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) have the same problems. These color schemes aren't designed for comparing color.

#### CIEDE2000

Luckily, there are scientists already trying to find a good way to compare colors. They came up with some elaborate methods, the latest one being [CIEDE2000](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference#CIEDE2000)

[image: CIEDE2000]

(the full formula described in the article is *huge*)

This metric takes human perception into consideration, like the fact that we seem to be unable to discern shades of blue very well. So I'd say we use this as our color difference function.

### The Color Picking Algorithm

#### Naive solution

Some answers suggested the following algorithm

```
colors = []
for n in range(n):
    success=False
    while not success:
        new_color = random_color()
        for color in colors:
            if distance(color, new_color)>far_enough:
                colors.append(new_color)
                success = True
                break
```

This algorithm has some problems:

1. The spacing of the colors isn't optimal. If we imagine the colors to be like numbers on a line, three numbers would be optimally spaced like this:

   |a-----b-----c|

   Packing an additional one number in there without moving a, b, and c is clearly worse than realigning all the colors.
2. **The algorithm isn't guaranteed to terminate**. What if there is no color that is far enough form the existing colors in the list? The loop will continue forever

#### Proper solution

Well.. I don't have one.

Comment: *This page is intended to provide helpful information for correct implementation of the CIEDE2000 color-difference formula.*
 http://www.ece.rochester.edu/~gsharma/ciede2000/

Comment: Using CIE is exactly what I did for my online tool here: http://phrogz.net/css/distinct-colors.html

Comment: Do take a look into the **Lab** and **HCL** colourspaces (HCL is perhaps the best one for generating colours for humans, but it has a concave domain). A notable tool is the iWantHue tool by medialab: http://tools.medialab.sciences-po.fr/iwanthue/

Answer (score 4):

You want to convert to HSL and then iterate through the values of the hue (H) while keeping the other 2 values constant.

For each value you [convert from HSL back to RGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Converting_to_RGB).

See my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288498/how-do-i-get-a-rainbow-color-gradient-in-c/2288547#2288547) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773226/generate-unique-colours/773243#773243).

If your N is very large and therefore the colors are NOT visually distinct you could at that point re-iterate over all of the same hues and change the other components to vary the saturation or luminosity.   So basically you could have a max number of hue values to use, and once that is hit you can start over with a different saturation or luminosity.

Comment: This doesn't utilize less bright and less saturated colors

Comment: If you want to, you easily can by randomizing those values while keeping a good mix of the hue.

Comment: @Brian: That will easily generate lots of gray-like colors.

Comment: @KennyTM no it won't.  My original suggestion was to simply keep the saturation and luminosity at constant values and iterate your hue values.  Of course you can randomize them slightly a little if you'd like to address @Otto Allmendinger's concern.

Comment: @Brian: So you're using a very small subset of colors which easily causes visually-indistinguishable colors.

Comment: @KennyTM: Agree, updated to address that problem.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer to your question, but, if *n* has a maximum value and your application allows it, you could use a predefined list of colors like this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_colors

One advantage is that you could show a humanly readable color name in a tooltip for people with color blindness.

Comment: If he needs to choose 3 colors, how does he prevent picking "Alizarin" and "Amaranth" and "Carmine" which nearly look the same?

Comment: @Otto - Using the formula for Color Difference you posted, or using a list including only colors that "look different". (BTW the three you mention look very distinct to me, but there are others that I see as identical, genetics I guess)

Comment: well, we can agree that they are all red which is too close. The color difference equation is just one piece of the puzzle, you have to come up with a better method than picking random colors sequentially and checking if they are too close to existing colors (I'll write up the details in my answer)

Answer (score 1):

For starters, don't use RGB space; it's hard to find a worse colour space for this problem.  (Depending on whether you're using the colours for display or for print you either have huge numbers of indistinguishable colours near black or near white.)

If you use Lab space, there are perceptual colour models (CIE 1996? and CIE 2000) for measuring the visual closeness of colours (for print and display respectively).

You don't say if you're going to compute the colours once and store the result, or if they need to be recomputed on the fly (and in that case if it has to be deterministic or not).  Obviously any discussion of how best to generate the set would depend on that.

Though I would suggest that evenly dividing the axes of the colour space (say into 8) and using those as initial points would be much more efficient than any random process.  Certainly you only need to compare any point to its neighbours (and only if they're already in the set), which will save you a huge number of comparisons.

Comment: It's tempting to use the LAB color space, but many of those coordinates don't map back to RGB space or the human visible gamut - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space . That makes it difficult to choose random colors from it.