# Color picker does not give gradient appearance

Tags: c#, .net, colors, system.drawing.color

i added below codes. But it generates to me 16 color. but i need 16 color between "red" and "khaki". i don't need gradient flow. My colors look like gradient flow. My colors must not closer to each other. Because i will use this codes return values in  chart columns. they are too near each other.

```
  static class Program
    {

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Form form = new Form();
            Color start = Color.Red, end = Color.Khaki;
            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            {
                int r = Interpolate(start.R, end.R, 15, i),
                    g = Interpolate(start.G, end.G, 15, i),
                    b = Interpolate(start.B, end.B, 15, i);

                Button button = new Button();
                button.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
                button.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
                form.Controls.Add(button);
                button.BringToFront();
            }

            Application.Run(form);
        }
        static int Interpolate(int start, int end, int steps, int count)
        {
            float s = start, e = end, final = s + (((e - s) / steps) * count);
            return (int)final;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to rewrite the question here. The code is clear enough, but I have no idea what you actually want.

Comment: The code you have above will generate the 16 colors "between" Red and Khaki. Are you saying you want a different distribution of colors, not on the linear gradient? You must make the question clearer.

Comment: yes i want different distribution of colors

Answer (score 2):

Here's the output of the program. <strike>I think he wants colors in the range of Red / Khaki, but aren't so close to each other.</strike> I think he wants something to choose complimentary colors similarly to http://www.colorschemer.com/online.html

[Example run http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/9256/20090612094934.png](http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/9256/20090612094934.png)

Comment: i want to see other color. Such as Brown or pink

Answer (score 2):

The revised text of question is pretty clear: you want 16 colors on a gradient "between" Red and Khaki where the visual difference between any two colors is visually more significant than the colors you chose are.

Perhaps a better title would be "What algorithm can I use to generate 16 visually distinctive colors between Red and Khaki?"

I don't think there is one. Red (255, 255, 0) and Khaki (255, 240, 230) just aren't that different: RGB difference = (0,15,-230)

If you divide it up in 16 *equal* steps like you do, the resultant colors are close enough together to look like a gradient as you said. If you were to use *unequal* steps, (perhaps a logarithmic scale), your results would be worse, at least at one end of your range.

I think you need to either **a)** choose different endpoints or **b)** choose discrete colors without trying to get them between your endpoints

Or you might want to look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470690/how-to-automatically-generate-n-distinct-colors) about choosing distinct colors.