# RGB to Munsell/Hue-and-Tone Conversion

Tags: image-processing, colors, rgb, hue, srgb

I want to convert colors from RGB to Hue and Tone(Chroma and Value) 130 System. I've searched but it seems there is no direct way for that, and no python library is available. Some references says RGB should be first convert to sRGB and after that we could generalize Munsell(Chroma, Value and Hue) to reach Hue and Tone from it. Another approach says we should convert RGB to XYZ and then extract Munsell and use it to make Hue and tone version. Some other approaches just quantize the RGB histogram and do not explain how exactly. Is there any clear way to do that? If anyone knows please help.

Comment: Have you looked into the colorsys python library yet? https://docs.python.org/3/library/colorsys.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Color Theory: How to convert Munsell HVC to RGB/HSB/HSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620663/color-theory-how-to-convert-munsell-hvc-to-rgb-hsb-hsl)