# islice on nested iterators

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterator

I'm trying to reuse the solution at the end of [How to automatically generate N "distinct" colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470690/how-to-automatically-generate-n-distinct-colors) using Python 2.7.

Unfortunately, the code below never returns, since even though `islice()` requests the first 100 iterations, it seems that the inner-map calls like

```
gethsvs = lambda: flatten(itertools.imap(genhsv, getfracs()))
```

force getting all iterations. Instead of passing the number of iterations to all lambda functions, is there a way to make an `islice()` call at the main code, as below, but making it get only the first 100 iterations in all inner maps as well?

```
import colorsys, itertools, numpy as np
from fractions import Fraction

def zenos_dichotomy():
    '''
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/2_%2B_1/4_%2B_1/8_%2B_1/16_%2B_%C2%B7_%C2%B7_%C2%B7
    '''
    for k in itertools.count():
        yield Fraction(1, 2 ** k)

def getfracs():
    '''
    [Fraction(0, 1), Fraction(1, 2), Fraction(1, 4), Fraction(3, 4), Fraction(1, 8), Fraction(3, 8), Fraction(5, 8), Fraction(7, 8), Fraction(1, 16), Fraction(3, 16), ...]
    [0.0, 0.5, 0.25, 0.75, 0.125, 0.375, 0.625, 0.875, 0.0625, 0.1875, ...]
    '''
    yield 0
    for k in zenos_dichotomy():
        i = k.denominator # [1,2,4,8,16,...]
        for j in range(1, i, 2):
            yield Fraction(j, i)

'''Can be used for the v in hsv to map linear values 0..1 to something that looks equidistant.'''
bias = lambda x: (np.sqrt(x / 3) / Fraction(2, 3) + Fraction(1, 3)) / Fraction(6, 5)

def genhsv(h):
    for s in [Fraction(6, 10)]: # optionally use range
        for v in [Fraction(8, 10), Fraction(5, 10)]: # could use range too
            yield (h, s, v) # use bias for v here if you use range

genrgb = lambda x: colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(*x)
flatten = itertools.chain.from_iterable
gethsvs = lambda: flatten(itertools.imap(genhsv, getfracs()))
getrgbs = lambda: itertools.imap(genrgb, gethsvs())

def genhtml(x):
    uint8tuple = itertools.imap(lambda y: int(y * 255), x)
    return 'rgb({},{},{})'.format(*uint8tuple)

gethtmlcolors = lambda: map(genhtml, getrgbs())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(list(itertools.islice(gethtmlcolors(), 100)))
```

Comment: some advice - you should probably wrap all this into a class, and use self param to pass arguments and variables back and forth, so you can have a class variable of the number of iterations you want shared with all the slicing and methods you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `map()` instead of `itertools.imap()` in your `gethtmlcolors` lambda:

```
gethtmlcolors = lambda: map(genhtml, getrgbs())
```

In python 2, `map()` will try and process all elements of the input iterable. Change that to use `imap()` and everything works:

```
gethtmlcolors = lambda: itertools.imap(genhtml, getrgbs())
```