# Get the next color for a chart/table?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've some table/chart. And I add series for them. Each series is identified by a color.

I'm searching how to choose the best color for a series that I add to my series.

The goal is to have a the next best color, depending of colors already used. Since I can add/remove series, I can't just have an array of color and taking the next one in the list.

I heard there was some MS guideline for that(only found this equivalent for [excel](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/guidelines-and-examples-for-sorting-and-filtering-data-by-color-HA010212590.aspx))

Any idea/link/method to do this?

EDIT: Found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb263947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which provide interessting informations about color contrast

EDIT2:
I tried to use a "Color Hue wheel": I only divide the wheel by the number of color that I need and I take the color at the start of the position. I also included a way to put some offset if we want to start with a different color.

It works, I got different colors, but I've the impression that we can do better. E.g. With an offset of 210°, 6 colors, i've those colors:
[image]
I think it's just an optical illusion, but the two last colors seems to be closer than others. The problem is that I've to deal with the user eye.

The whole "Hue" looks like this[image]
With the eye, we can see that there some color that looks like more different than other(like the cyan). For me the green seems to be larger than the yellow, ...

Seems that it exists a notion of colors being of [perceptually linear colors](http://phrogz.net/tmp/colordifferences/), do you know if there is a algorithm allowing me to get a Perceptually linear color array? Then it will be easy to take colors that I need

Comment: I've had some success using [HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) color coordinates for such calculation. You could, more or less, fix the S and V values, and just calculate the H value to find a suitable color.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it was my first try, I check the number of images I need, I divide 360 by the number and then get the color at this position. But I've the impression that we can do better. I'm updating the answer

Comment: Well, for suitably small numbers, up to 10-ish, I guess, you could just set the color manually (1 series - blue, 2 series - blue and red, 3, blue, red, yellow, etc...) and use the color wheel above that number.

Comment: @SWeko: Since the user must have the possibility to customize its color, I don't think it's possible, because our "Algorithm" should be able to compute the next most distinctive color based on existings one(which is basically possible by checking the most different "H" of our HSV value.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [How to automatically generate N "distinct" colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470690/how-to-automatically-generate-n-distinct-colors) but...

This is what I did when faced with a similar problem.

I created as table of 32 nicely distributed and distinct colours. I did it once. When I have to present more than 32 I just repeat the colours. I decided that 32 distinct series was more than good enough for my dataset (I'm not aware that more then 32 series has actually been used in a real life scenario).

A variant of this is to change the colour slightly when you go over the size of the reference table, using a crude change of adding 11111 to it.

I found this is a very simple approach with little room for errors.

Most of (all?) algorithms which take the number of needed colours and generate a list of distinct colours suffer from the problem of changing colours of existing series when a new one is added which I find a blocker as users would normally expect that Series X is black and Series Y is yellow etc, even if they add a new series.

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended by measuring the color distance. And accept this only if the distance is bigger than a trigger.

To do this, I iterate on my HsvColor, then I convert it to Rgb -> XYZ -> Lab(CIE L*a*b) which is a perceptually linear color scale. I based my code on this: http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_DeltaE_CMC.html