# Color image based on K classes and colors

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision

I have written code to take an image in, segment out important objects, and calculate features about the objects.  I then broke the objects in to K classes where K = 5 - 35 to get different representations.  What I would like to do now, is given K, save a mask where each of the objects are a different color.

What I am struggling to determine, is some method to identify what colors to use for the different object classes.

Basically what I am looking for is a function:

```
get_rgb(k):
```

Where k is the number of classes and the return is a list of RGB (or some other color representation).  I am using python and I have been trying to use color_maps in matplotlib, but I have not been successful with that.

Thanks for any help.

Edit: What I am looking for is K different colors to use.  So if K = 3, it could be [[255,0,0],[0,255,0],[0,0,255]].  These colors would then be used to mask the input image, which is something I can do already, I just need a way to determine the colors.

Comment: Not clear on what you're asking. How do you want to identify colors from each object class? Does it matter if you arbitrarily choose K fixed colors? Or are you looking for colors that are specific to their objects, e.g. a red ball will result in a mask that is colored red?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are just trying to generate K distinct colors. There are so many solutions here already:
[How to automatically generate N "distinct" colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470690/how-to-automatically-generate-n-distinct-colors/4382138#4382138) (it even has a [solution in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470690/how-to-automatically-generate-n-distinct-colors/9701141#9701141) that has exactly the function you want).