# How do I generate random dark colors in C#?

Tags: c#, colors

I generate a random color this way:

```
 var random = new Random();
 var color = String.Format("#{0:X6}", random.Next(0x1000000));
```

How can I exclude colors brighter than a certain value?

Comment: I know it's old question. In case someone needs, check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56848413/2417445

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An quite simple way to get rid of the "upper half" of brightes colors is to mask the result via

```
random.Next(0x1000000) & 0x7F7F7F
```

Comment: if you do `string.Format("#{0:x}",random.Next(0x1000000) & 0x7F7F7F);` in some cases result will be 5 hexadecimal numbers. Do not forget x6 format.

Comment: What happened here? Can you link to some documentation?

Comment: What if i want to get rid of dark colors, and keep the bright ones!?

Answer (score 7):

One way to do this is to generate colours in the [*HSV/HSL colour-space*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV), and then convert to RGB (the Wikipedia article tells you how to do that).

The advantage of HSV is that one of the components (V) corresponds to "brightness".  So if you generate H, S and V independently and randomly, but restrict V to low values, then you will get dark colours.

Comment: here is a [link](http://www.splinter.com.au/converting-hsv-to-rgb-colour-using-c/) on how to do the conversion in c#