# Random color in C#

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, gdi+, gdi

Is there any way to simplify this line of code? Are two calls to `Color.FromArgb()` really necessary?

```
Color c = Color.FromArgb(255, Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToInt32(rand.Next(0x1000000))));
```

Without the duplicated `Color.FromArgb()` call I get only `Alpha=0` colors.

References:

[How do I generate random dark colors in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396201/how-do-i-generate-random-dark-colors-in-c)

Comment: Well, one thing you can remove is `Convert.ToInt32`, because `rand.Next` (I'm assuming `System.Random`) already returns an `Int32`.

Comment: @Corak: You are right!

Comment: That really should be simple enough !!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just tried this in LinqPad and it seemed to do the trick:

```
var random = new Random();
System.Drawing.Color c;
unchecked
{
    var n = (int)0xFF000000 + (random.Next(0xFFFFFF) & 0x7F7F7F);
    Console.WriteLine($"ARGB: {n}");
    c = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(n);
}
Console.WriteLine($"A: {c.A}");
Console.WriteLine($"R: {c.R}");
Console.WriteLine($"G: {c.G}");
Console.WriteLine($"B: {c.B}");
```

More concisely, it would be:

```
var random = new Random();
Color c;
unchecked
{
    c = Color.FromArgb((int)0xFF000000 + (random.Next(0xFFFFFF) & 0x7F7F7F));
}
```

Or if you want to get really funky with bit manipulation (this is not more efficient, just saves you typing some 0s):

```
c = Color.FromArgb((int)(0xFF << 24 ^ (random.Next(0xFFFFFF) & 0x7F7F7F)));
```

Original poster pointed out that an extra pair of brackets eliminates the need for unchecked:

```
c = Color.FromArgb((int)(0xFF000000 + (random.Next(0xFFFFFF) & 0x7F7F7F)));
```

Bit of an explanation. ARGB is using a signed 32 bit int to represent four bytes, A, R, G, and B. We want the colour to be solid, so A needs to be 255 hence:
0xFF000000
Then random.Next(0xFFFFFF) generates a pseudo-random 24 bit number taking care of the R, G and B bytes. As the question only wanted dark colours we mask off the most significant bit of each byte. For a simple example, say the RNG spat out the max value (equivalent to white):

0xFFFFFF = 111111111111111111111111

We then do a bitwise AND to chop off the most significant bits:

0x7F7F7F = 011111110111111101111111

111111111111111111111111 & 011111110111111101111111 = 011111110111111101111111

Comment: Maybe `Convert.ToInt32()` helps to remove `unchecked` statement?

Comment: No, that causes an overflow exception. The problem is you need the top 8 bits to be set to 1 which means you end up with a negative number in signed int terms.

Comment: It works with an additional couple of brackets: standard 
`Color.FromArgb((int) (0xFF000000 + rand.Next(0xFFFFFF)))` and dark
 `Color.FromArgb((int)(0xFF000000 + (rand.Next(0xFFFFFF) & 0x7F7F7F)))`

Comment: Huh, you're right. Wouldn't expect that to work... Nice.

Answer (score 4):

You could just use the overload that takes the individual color components. You're trading off 2 calls to `FromArgb()` for 3 random numbers.

```
var rand = new Random();
Color c = Color.FromArgb(rand.Next(256), rand.Next(256), rand.Next(256));
```

Comment: No, sorry. The reference is misleading. Full color is what I am actually after.

Comment: No problem. I switched it back.

Answer (score 1):

There is [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zys7833(v=vs.110).aspx), that accepts only one argument:

```
Color c = Color.FromArgb(rand.Next(int.MaxValue) | (0xFF0000));
```

`0xFF0000` - to create solid color (alpha = 255)

Comment: This would create, at most, a half-transparent color. I think the alpha channel still needs to be 255.

Comment: `| unchecked((int)0xFF000000)` - otherwise compiler might complain.

Comment: Do you mean `Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToInt32(rand.Next(int.MaxValue) | (0xFF000000)))`?

Answer (score 1):

I created [library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ColorHelper/) (MIT license) for work with colors. Also I added implementation with random generator.

Examples:

Get random color:

```
RGB rgb = ColorGenerator.GetRandomColor<RGB>();
HEX hex = ColorGenerator.GetRandomColor<HEX>();
CMYK cmyk = ColorGenerator.GetRandomColor<CMYK>();
```

Another methods:

```
GetLightRandomColor<type>();
GetDarkRandomColor<type>();
GetRedRandomColor<type>();
GetGreenRandomColor<type>();
GetBlueRandomColor<type>();
```

Links:
[Github](https://github.com/iamartyom/ColorHelper) and [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ColorHelper/).